# Is there a way of getting "marginal effects" from a `glmer` object

Tags: r, lme4, marginal-effects

I am estimating random effects logit model using `glmer` and I would like to report Marginal Effects for the independent variables. For `glm` models, package `mfx` helps compute marginal effects. Is there any package or function for `glmer` objects?

Thanks for your help.

A reproducible example is given below

```
## mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
## as of 2020-08-24:
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank) #creating ranks
id <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(mydata)/2), times=c(2)) #creating ID variable
mydata <- cbind(mydata,data.frame(id,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) 
set.seed(12345)
mydata$ran <- runif(nrow(mydata),0,1) #creating a random variable

library(lme4)
cfelr <- glmer(admit ~ (1 | id) + rank + gpa + ran + gre, data=mydata ,family = binomial)
summary(cfelr)
```

Comment: It's considerably more complicated because you have to decide how to marginalize over the random effects as well.  I have a hack/short-cut solution I'll post soon.

Comment: never mind, it doesn't work (`logitmfx` internally refits `glm`).

Comment: you might try asking on `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` (include a link to this question).

Comment: @BenBolker Did you ever come across a working solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach using the `margins()` package:

```
library(margins)
library(lme4)

gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period +
                 (1 | herd),
             data = cbpp,
             family = binomial)

m <- margins(gm1, data = cbpp)
m
```

Comment: Exceptional answer.

Comment: The documentation for `margins::margins` doesn't include gmlerMod as a compatible model class, but it is compatible with lmerMod. Do you know if everything that margins would do with a lmerMod is appropriate for a glmerMod?

Answer (score 4):

This is a much less technical answer, but perhaps provides a useful resource.  I am a fan of the `sjPlot` package which provides plots of marginal effects of glmer objects, like so:

```
library(sjPlot)
sjp.glmer(cfelr, type = "eff")
```

The package provides a lot of options for exploring a glmer model's fixed and random effects as well. https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [ggeffects-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggeffects) (examples in the [package-vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/vignettes/marginaleffects.html)). So, for your code this might look like this:

```
library(ggeffects)
# dat is a data frame with marginal effects
dat <- ggpredict(cfelr, term = "rank")
plot(dat)
```

or you use, as Benjamin described, the You could use the [sjPlot-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjPlot), using the `plot_model()` function with plot-type `"pred"` (this simply wraps the ggeffects package for marginal effect plots):

```
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(cfelr, type = "pred", term = "rank")
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution does not answer the question,

#### "Is there a way of getting “marginal effects” from a `glmer` object",

but rather,

#### "Is there a way of getting marginal logistic regression coefficients from a conditional logistic regression with one random intercept?"

I am only offering this write-up because the reproducible example provided was a conditional logistic regression with one random intercept and I'm intending to be helpful.  Please do not downvote; I will take down if this answer is deemed too off topic.

The R-code is [based on the work of Patrick Heagerty (click "View Raw" to see pdf)](https://github.com/swihart/lnMLE_1.0-2/blob/master/inst/doc/lnMLEhelp.pdf), and I include a reproducible example below from my github version of his lnMLE package (excuse the warnings at installation -- I'm shoehorning Patrick's non-CRAN package).  I'm omitting the output for all except the last line, `compare`, which shows the fixed effect coefficients side-by-side.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("lnMLE_1.0-2", "swihart")
library(lnMLE)
## run the example from the logit.normal.mle help page
## see also the accompanying document (click 'View Raw' on page below:)
## https://github.com/swihart/lnMLE_1.0-2/blob/master/inst/doc/lnMLEhelp.pdf
data(eye_race)
attach(eye_race)
marg_model <- logit.normal.mle(meanmodel = value ~ black,
                           logSigma= ~1,
                           id=eye_race$id,
                           model="marginal",
                           data=eye_race,
                           tol=1e-5,
                           maxits=100,
                           r=50)
marg_model
cond_model <- logit.normal.mle(meanmodel = value ~ black,
                           logSigma= ~1,
                           id=eye_race$id,
                           model="conditional",
                           data=eye_race,
                           tol=1e-5,
                           maxits=100,
                           r=50)
cond_model
compare<-round(cbind(marg_model$beta, cond_model$beta),2)
colnames(compare)<-c("Marginal", "Conditional")
compare
```

The output of the last line:

> compare

```
            Marginal Conditional

(Intercept)    -2.43       -4.94

black           0.08        0.15
```

I attempted the reproducible example given, but had problems with both the glmer and lnMLE implementations; again I only include output pertaining to the comparison results and the warnings from the `glmer()` call:

```
##original question / answer... glmer() function gave a warning and the lnMLE did not fit well...
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank) #creating ranks
id <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(mydata)/2), times=c(2)) #creating ID variable
mydata <- cbind(mydata,data.frame(id,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
set.seed(12345)
mydata$ran <- runif(nrow(mydata),0,1) #creating a random variable

library(lme4)
cfelr <- glmer(admit ~ (1 | id) + rank + gpa + ran + gre, 
               data=mydata,
               family = binomial)
```

Which gave:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00161047 (tol = 0.001, component 2)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

but I foolishly went on without rescaling, trying to apply the `logit.normal.mle` to the example given.  However, the conditional model doesn't converge or produce standard error estimates,

```
summary(cfelr)
library(devtools)
install_github("lnMLE_1.0-2", "swihart")
library(lnMLE)

mydata$rank2 = mydata$rank==2
mydata$rank3 = mydata$rank==3
mydata$rank4 = mydata$rank==4

cfelr_cond =  logit.normal.mle(meanmodel = admit ~ rank2+rank3+rank4+gpa+ran+gre, 
                               logSigma = ~1 , 
                               id=id, 
                               model="conditional", 
                               data=mydata, 
                               r=50, 
                               tol=1e-6, 
                               maxits=500)
cfelr_cond


cfelr_marg =  logit.normal.mle(meanmodel = admit ~ rank2+rank3+rank4+gpa+ran+gre,
                               logSigma = ~1 , 
                               id=id, 
                               model="marginal", 
                               data=mydata, 
                               r=50, 
                               tol=1e-6, 
                               maxits=500)
cfelr_marg


compare_glmer<-round(cbind(cfelr_marg$beta, cfelr_cond$beta,summary(cfelr)$coeff[,"Estimate"]),3)
colnames(compare_glmer)<-c("Marginal", "Conditional","glmer() Conditional")
compare_glmer
```

The last line of which reveals that the conditional model from `cfelr_cond` did not evaluate a conditional model but just returned the marginal coefficients and no standard errors.

```
>     compare_glmer

            Marginal Conditional glmer() Conditional

(Intercept)   -4.407      -4.407              -4.425

rank2         -0.667      -0.667              -0.680

rank3         -1.832      -1.833              -1.418

rank4         -1.930      -1.930              -1.585

gpa            0.547       0.548               0.869

ran            0.860       0.860               0.413

gre            0.004       0.004               0.002
```

I hope to iron out these issues.  Any help/comments appreciated.  I'll give status updates when I can.